How to pass environment variables to String.fromEnvironment() when running dart run build_runner
I'm using the envied_generator and build_runner packages. I want to modify the path within @Envied(path: const String.fromEnvironment('environment')) based on the environment.
I launch my Flutter app through VS Code launch configuration which triggers a prelaunch task (dart run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs). However, const String.fromEnvironment('environment') always returns an empty value. I attempted to pass the environment variable using the --define flag, but it didn’t work.
How can I correctly pass environment variables to String.fromEnvironment() when running build_runner?
UPD:
My launch.json file:
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Dev-Debug",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "flutterMode": "debug",
            "args": ["--flavor", "dev",
            "--dart-define", "environment=dev"],
            "preLaunchTask": "build_runner_dev"
           }
        ]
    }

My tasks.json file:
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
      {
          "label": "build_runner_dev",
          "type": "shell",
          "command": "dart run build_runner build -- --define=environment=dev",
          "group": {
              "kind": "build",
              "isDefault": true
          },
      }
  ]
}


It might be informative to include the configuration file launch.json with your post.

Thank you! I've just added it

Isn't the variable you are defining called environment? Seems you are trying to read a variable called env.

I'm sorry it's a typo in description. I changed it

I tried the command option you are showing above:
dart run build_runner build -- --define=environment=dev

and the constant env is always the empty string:
final env = const String.fromEnvironment('environment'); // Empty String


However, build_runner has its own --define option, see How is the configuration for a builder resolved?.
The default options for envied are listed below:
targets:
  $default:
    builders:
      envied_generator|envied:
        options:
          path: .env.custom
          override: true 


To set the option path from the command line try:
$ dart run build_runner build --define=envied_generator:envied=path="custom_path" --define=envied_generator:envied=override=true

This should overwrite the default build option set in the build.yaml file.
Updated the command, see Drompai's comment below.

It didn't work until I added this --define=envied_generator:envied=override=true to the end of your command and now it's working. Thank you very much!
